# Both .getJSON() and .ajax() not working for REST API call

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery

Can someone explain me how to make a REST call using jQuery/Javascript? I tried using the `.getJSON()` and `.ajax()`, but neither helped me.

This is the REST URL :

> http://ws1.airnowgateway.org/GatewayWebServiceREST/Gateway.svc/forecastbyzipcode?zipcode=94954&date=2010-01-15&format=json&key=API_KEY

Code:

```
$.getJSON('http://ws1.airnowgateway.org/GatewayWebServiceREST/Gateway.svc/forecastbyzipcode?zipcode='+zip+'&format=json&key=**<KEY HERE>**',

    function(data)
    {

        alert(data.AQI);
    }

);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://ws1.airnowgateway.org/GatewayWebServiceREST/Gateway.svc/forecastbyzipcode',
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'zipcode='+zip+'&format=json&key=**<KEY HERE>**',
    success: function() { alert('get completed'); }
});
```

Comment: Start Googling for "cross domain ajax."

Comment: @RoyiNamir Still considered cross-domain... `"However, the common moniker for these requests, cross-domain, tends to be misleading. While a request from one domain to another is obviously cross-origin, browsers are much more picky than that.
For example, a request from foo.domain.com to bar.domain.com is just as much cross-origin request as one to abc.com. That’s not quite as intuitive as the traditional cross-domain scenario, but requires the same consideration."` - http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/

Comment: Yep, by default browsers doesn't allow javascript to perform requests to different domains / protocols.. of course, there are several workarounds to this

Comment: Also, question title should be updated to something like "How to make cross-domain requests using jquery"...

Comment: @RoyiNamir np - Jayaram feel free to follow the link I've provided, in my comment above, to gain more insight on the topic...

Comment: If your server can be made to support JSONP or does already, that might be your answer.

Comment: @Jayaram You should reset your key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are a couple of problems. First, you need to add `&callback=?` to the end of the querystring to allow the crossdomain.

```
$.getJSON('http://ws1.airnowgateway.org/GatewayWebServiceREST/Gateway.svc/forecastbyzipcode?zipcode=94954&format=json&key=B868EA39-1D92-412A-96DE-DCF5ED30236D&callback=?',

  function(data)
  {
    alert(data.forecast[0]);
  }

);
```

You will then get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error. This is because you are expecting `json` data, but the headers on the server are sending `text/html` - not `application/json`.  Take a look at the console when you [run this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CuBFB/), you'll see the errors.

Therefore, you can't get the data from cross domain because you have to be using jsonp - which **requires** the header to be sent correctly.

If this is your api, then you just need to send the correct header, otherwise, you need to get with the developers there and ask them to fix it.

---

**Alternatively**

If neither of those above options work, you could always create a proxy script that would get the contents of the json feed for you and echo it out. Here's one in PHP:

```
<?php
// myproxy.php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$zip = $_GET['zip'];
$results = file_get_contents('http://ws1.airnowgateway.org/GatewayWebServiceREST/Gateway.svc/forecastbyzipcode?zipcode=' . $zip . '&format=json&key=B868EA39-1D92-412A-96DE-DCF5ED30236D');

echo $results;
?>
```

Then, you would just point your $.getJSON to this script on your server:

```
$.getJSON('/myproxy.php?zip='+zip,

  function(data)
  {
    var mydata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(mydata.forecast[0]);
  }

);
```

Comment: Got into a new problem. the rest URL has a zipcode, how can I send the zip code dynamically after asking the user ?

Comment: You can send it as a querystring to the myproxy.php script: `/myproxy.php?zip=12345` -- then use the `$_GET['zip']` in your php script to dynamically add it there. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi I did as you said,

wrote the script, tested it, it works perfectly, 

but inside the .getJSON, it doesn't alert me the array.

when i try to display the data variable it says object object and the mydata variable it says null

no matter for how many different zip codes i try, it still gives me the same output.